# Html.Raw and quotes in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to pass object as a parameter to `onclick` event for in View, so I write code like this

`<a href="#" onclick="my_cool_function(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model)))">cool action</a>`
and HTML page that was rendered has incorrect html code

but problem is disappearing when change double quotes to single quotes:
`<a href="#" onclick='my_cool_function(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model)))'>cool action</a>`

Difference in page rendering:

[image]

I can't figure out why this happen. Maybe some better method exists to pass object as function parameter in this case?

This problem appears last few days. Before that it worked ok, and no any changes in components was made (but I didn't check generated html before, maybe browser could process both formats properly before)

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to pass a string literal as the function parameter, so you need to enclose the text in double or single quotes (you’re missing this part). Because all of this happens inside a HTML attribute value, this value too needs to be in quotes. The syntax you’re looking for is the following, where " and ' may be swapped:

```
<a onclick="my_cool_function('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model))')"></a>
```

Tbh, I’m not sure you even need `Html.Raw()` here.

Also, because of all the nested quotes, this won’t work if quotes appear in the Json syntax, so you can’t encode string values or property names. If you only need Json arrays with numbers in them, it should be fine.

Otherwise, you might split things up into two attributes:

```
<a data-model='@Json.Encode(model)' onclick="my_cool_function(this.dataset.model)"></a>
```

You still need the single quotes because Json may contain double quotes.